# correct implementation of asymmetric cryptography

Tags: encryption-asymmetric

I have mobile apps that make requests to server. I am thinking of using asymmetric cryptography where the private key resides in the server. The public key will be distributed to all users. Meaning all users will use the same public key for encryption. Is this way viable?

Comment: Yep, this is exactly how public-key crypto works! :)

Comment: Because I am worried whether using same public key for all users is the correct way.

Comment: Again, yes, that's how public-key crypto works. It's called a public key because it's publicly available and everyone can use it. The whole idea is to avoid creating a new key for every user.